# Recaptcha V3 invalid action Name

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Guys im getting this error only in few pages in laravel which contains dynamically generated Urls...
**recaptcha__en.js:161 Invalid action name, may only include "A-Za-z/_". Do not include user-specific information.**

anyone have an idea to solve this???

Answer (score 3):

The official Re-Captcha documentation says if the URL contains a "-" (dash), the reCaptcha wont work and they have added the dash to a set of attributes to refrain from using in the URL in order to work with reCaptcha.. i have added a new plugin called mathCaptcha to work with that certain form...its easy to implement and configure

Comment: Good point. It also does not work if the URL has slash '/' or '\'.